# How to draw two rows per one object inside autoTable

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using the [jsPdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) and [autoTable](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable) to draw my data on a table and then save it to`.pdf` file.

This is more or less the effect that I want to achieve: [image: table with data].

AutoTable allowed me to easily put my data when I had to draw only one row per Object.

Is there a simple way to achieve this result?

Comment: Hopefully these should help: https://simonbengtsson.github.io/jsPDF-AutoTable/#spans and https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/blob/master/examples/examples.js

Comment: Thanks @StuFurlong . I had a look but unfortunately, I couldn't find what I was looking for. I think the best solution will be to draw my data into html and then draw it to PDF